# PyDev problem staring project

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I have downloaded the zip archive (my only option) and installed it as suggested by unzipping into the dropin folder. When I try to start a project the problem occurs:

"Plug-in org.python.pydev was unable to load class org.python.pydev.ui.wizard.project.PythonProjectWizard"

I've googled and the only suggestion is to re-download and re-install as it might be a corrupted install. Done that, no good. Any more suggestions? Seems PyDev have a lot of troubles getting the zip alternative to work... (judging by other similar posts)

This is regardless of Eclipse version.

I run under WinXP.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Try superuser?

Comment: Well, its a question about programming...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no luck with this. Eventually I had to download it through Eclipse download manager and it worked. I guess they have some issues with the automatic plugin functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to maintain in Eclipse the location of your Python installation. Open in the Window ▸ Preference ▸ Pydev ▸ Interpreter Python menu.

[image]

Press the New button and enter the path to python.exe in your Python installation directory. For Linux and Mac OS X users this is normally /usr/bin/python.
[image]

The result should look like the following:

[image]

Click on Apply and then ok

Comment: Just want to add that I did do all that. It didn't work. It could have been a temporary bug. Regardless I'm not using Eclipse any more.